# Git remote heroku disappeared

Tags: git, heroku

Just had something weird happen. I'm developing and pushing my application to Heroku for about a week now and an hour ago I suddenly get this error:

```
Pushing master to heroku
Warning: fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Use --force to continue.
```

Something removed the heroku remote from my config, I thought. But looking closer revealed that the remote is still specified:

```
D:\wamp\www\heroku\sodexo-poc\poc>git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/sodexo-poc.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/sodexo-poc.git (push)
```

It's also available in my `.git/config` file. But whatever I tried, it still doesn't recognize the remote named git. I can only push to it using `git push heroku +master`, because the remote was further ahead than my local branch (which also puzzles me).

I tried things like resetting the keys, removing and adding the remote again (in various configurations) and even creating a new app with a new remote and pushing to that one.